# mysqli_query not working. Missing connection?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, error-handling, database-connection

I am new here. I have searched all but Unable to get exact answer. I am executing a  mysql_query in login.php but it is not working. I tried checking by placing an if condition just after mysql_query and confirmed that query is not returning result as true. have I failed establishing a proper connection to mysql database?  please guide.

//login.php

```html
<?php


include_once("Connection.php"); 

if(!$con) {
die  ("Cannot Connect" . mysql_error());
}


$username = $_POST['UserName'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

$result = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE username = $username AND userpass = $password";
$sql=mysqli_query($con,$result);

if($sql == FALSE) { 
    echo "this"; // TODO: better error handling
}



else{
 
$res=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
}



$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    echo $num_rows;

if ($num_rows > 0) {

session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header ("location: path.html");
}

else{
 
 echo $num_rows;
 //header ("location: index.htm");
 //exit ();
}


?>
```

//connection.php

```html
<?php


$con=mysqlI_connect("localhost","root","","taxisystem" );  /* Connecting to sql */
/* we have used $con to store it in variable as we will have to use it multiple times! */

/*update: Now we will use connection.php instead! :) */


?>
```

Comment: what is the error you get??

Comment: at the moment I have placed this if-else condition and if condition is printing this.  Proving that $res is not true.   Plus if I  remove these  if else clause than error comes for mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","taxisystem" );
```

on connection page. And you are mixing it up with mysql -

```
<?php


include_once("Connection.php"); 

if(!$con) {
die  ("Cannot Connect" . mysqli_error($con));
}


$username = $_POST['UserName'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

$result = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE username = '$username' AND userpass = '$password'";
$sql=mysqli_query($con,$result);

if($sql == FALSE) { 
    echo "this"; // TODO: better error handling
}



else{

$res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}



$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    echo $num_rows;

if ($num_rows > 0) {

session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header ("location: path.html");
}

else{

    echo $num_rows;
    //header ("location: index.htm");
    //exit ();
}


?>
```

And please do some escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct. You have to add single quotes around the variables because that are char types.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE username = '$username' AND userpass = '$password'";
```

A better way to work with sql are prepared statements.

Another problem is a type in connect it must be `mysqli` not `mysqlI`

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","taxisystem" );
```

Comment: Thank  you Janes that helped me pulling out of that if else loop.  Still I have error on line 25 saying mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. The format I used  is it not the proper? kindly help @jens

Comment: @Worried_user You have to use `mysqli_fetch_array`. But you use `mysql_fetch_array` (missing `i`)